# How to upload an image in folder with database in asp.net on remote server?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I face this problem on uploading time:

> Access to the path
>   'D:\inetpub\vhosts\rajschool.com\httpdocs\Photo\3d_529 - Copy.jpg' is
>   denied.

My code for uploading image is:

```
protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    string imagefolder = "Photo";
    string savepath;
    string savefile;


    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        savepath = Path.Combine(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, imagefolder);
        savefile = Path.Combine(savepath, FileUpload1.FileName);
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(savefile);
        SqlDataSource1.Insert();
        lblmgs.Text = "successfully upload";

    }

}
```

Comment: Have you created the folder and set the required privileges?

Answer (score 0):

The IIS_USR should have the write access to that path

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not about your code , you must check you host control panel and change the "D:\inetpub\vhosts\rajschool.com\httpdocs\Photo" permission

Answer (score 0):

if you are using parallel plex then you may give that folder "Photo" the permission of read and write . Give full permission to the user.
Go to the filemanager, select folder, click on icon which looks like a lock, go to advance,select IURS and IWPD user from list and grant full permission.